# Timestamp Date & Time Format - Apps Script - Format Date and Time

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I can't get the time-stamp format in a spreadsheet cell to also include the time.  Currently, it only produces the date.  What do I need to change to get the time-stamp to show both date and time?

Like this:

3/17/2015 10:57:45

```
function onEdit(event)
{
  var ss = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if(r.getColumn() == 8){ //To check if update cell in Column, 1 means first column.
    if(r.getValue() == "Resolved"){ //To check the value is equal to Resolved
      ss.getRange('L'+r.getRow()).setValue(new Date()); //Set column B1 value to current date.
      date = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT", "HH:mm:ss");
    }else{
      ss.getRange('L'+r.getRow()).setValue('');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 15):

You need to use:

```
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

There is an example in the documentation:

[Google Documentation - formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/100644/27487 recommends *not* using Utilities.formatDate().

Comment: There are definitely good reasons to not change the spreadsheet cell format to text, and save the date as text.

Answer (score 10):

In you code, get the time zone of the script like this:

```
var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, "MM-dd-yyyy | HH:mm:ss");
```